# << "[read] I/O error: Read timed out" immediately upon sending headers

Tags: http, spring-boot, networking, apache-httpclient-4.x, tcp

We see time-outs during some calls to external REST service from within a Spring Boot application. They do not seem to occur when we connect to the REST service directly. Debug logging on org.apache.http has given us a very peculiar aspect of the failing requests: it contains an inbound log entry `'<< "[read] I/O error: Read timed out"'` in the middle of sending headers - the same millisecond the first headers were sent.

How can we see an inbound 'Read timed out' a few milliseconds after sending the first headers? And why does it not immediately interrupt the request/connection with a time-out, but instead waits the full 4500ms until it times out with an exception?

Here is our production log for a failing request, redacted. Note the 4500ms delay between lines two and three. My question is about the occurrence of `http-outgoing-104 << "[read] I/O error: Read timed out"` at `16:55:08.258`, not the first one on line 2.

```
16:55:12.764    Connection released: [id: 104][route: {s}-><<website-redacted>>:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 20]
16:55:12.763    http-outgoing-104 << "[read] I/O error: Read timed out"
16:55:08.259    http-outgoing-104 >> "<<POST Body Redacted>>"
16:55:08.259    http-outgoing-104 >> "[\r][\n]"
16:55:08.258    http-outgoing-104: set socket timeout to 4500
16:55:08.258    Executing request POST <<Endpoint Redacted>> HTTP/1.1
16:55:08.258    Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
16:55:08.258    Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
16:55:08.258    Connection leased: [id: 104][route: {s}-><<website-redacted>>:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
....
16:55:08.258    http-outgoing-104 >> "POST <<Endpoint Redacted>> HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
16:55:08.258    http-outgoing-104 >> "Accept: text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*[\r][\n]"
16:55:08.258    http-outgoing-104 >> Cookie: <<Redacted>>
16:55:08.258    http-outgoing-104 >> "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
16:55:08.258    http-outgoing-104 >> "Connection: close[\r][\n]"
16:55:08.258    http-outgoing-104 >> "X-B3-SpanId: <<ID>>[\r][\n]"
16:55:08.258    http-outgoing-104 << "[read] I/O error: Read timed out"
16:55:08.258    http-outgoing-104 >> "X-Span-Name: https:<<Endpoint Redacted>>[\r][\n]"
16:55:08.258    http-outgoing-104 >> "X-B3-TraceId: <<ID>>[\r][\n]"
16:55:08.258    http-outgoing-104 >> "X-B3-ParentSpanId: <<ID>>[\r][\n]"
16:55:08.258    http-outgoing-104 >> "Content-Length: 90[\r][\n]"
16:55:08.258    http-outgoing-104 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_172)[\r][\n]"
16:55:08.258    http-outgoing-104 >> "Cookie: <<Redacted>>"
16:55:08.258    http-outgoing-104 >> "Host: <<Host redacted>>[\r][\n]"
16:55:08.258    http-outgoing-104 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
16:55:08.258    http-outgoing-104 >> "X-B3-Sampled: 1[\r][\n
```

**Update 1: a second occurrence:**
In another request that timed out the same behavior roughly occurs, but the timeout message is logged even before sending headers and eventually receiving the actual timeout. *Note*: this request is actually older, after it I have configured the request to include 'Connection: close' to circumvent a firewall dropping the connection under 'Keep Alive'.

```
19:28:08.102    http-outgoing-36 << "[read] I/O error: Read timed out"
19:28:08.102    http-outgoing-36: Shutdown connection
19:28:08.102    http-outgoing-36: Close connection
19:28:03.598    http-outgoing-36 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
19:28:03.598    http-outgoing-36 >> "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
...
19:28:03.598    http-outgoing-36 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
...
19:28:03.597    http-outgoing-36 >> Cookie: ....
19:28:03.597    http-outgoing-36 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
19:28:03.597    http-outgoing-36 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_172)
19:28:03.596    Connection leased: [id: 36][route: {s}-><< Site redacted >>:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
19:28:03.596    http-outgoing-36: set socket timeout to 4500
19:28:03.596    Executing request POST  HTTP/1.1
19:28:03.596    Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
19:28:03.596    http-outgoing-36 << "[read] I/O error: Read timed out"
19:28:03.594    Connection request: [route: {s}-><< Site redacted >>:443][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
19:28:03.594    Auth cache not set in the context
```

**Update 2: added HttpClientBuilder configuration**

```java
RequestConfig.Builder requestBuilder = RequestConfig.custom()
        .setSocketTimeout(socketTimeout)
        .setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout);

CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
        .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestBuilder.build())
        .build();

HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory rf = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
return new RestTemplate(rf);
```

Comment: As seen in the record `Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3`, an HTTP client pool is used. I would suggest to enable debugging on the pool to get more information. Connection seems to be dropped on the remote endpoint.

Comment: We tried to eliminate the remote server as an option by calling it directly from our local machines and never saw the same behavior - but it is possible we were just not lucky enough to get a failure.

If the remote server drops the connection, why does it not immediately stop on our end?

Comment: Is it possible you are cutting thread name to the right? Perhaps it's thread `http-outgoing-1041` failing with messages from thread `http-outgoing-1047` interleaved.

Comment: The 104 is repeated in the lines that are from other loggers and is the connection ID in this case: `Connection leased: [id: 104]`, so I'm pretty sure it's not that. Good thought.

Comment: Makes no sense to have all these events at the same millisecond (258) :p

Comment: Your debug log seems not in correct order as in code, have you modified it somehow?

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn The log is original and from Kibana. The order of the log is according to timestamp. I have only edited out 'September 7th 2018' on the beginning of each line for compactness.

Comment: @Spork Could you show your HttpClientBuilder configuration?

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn I haven't really configured much - basically using the Spring Boot defaults except for custom timeouts. I've updated my question to include it.

Comment: @Spork: are you able to figure out the cause and solution, I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @Jayesh the answer to the question why this could be logged this way I never did find - I did find out that a loadbalancer within our network did not accept any POST request with the '<' character, while PUT requests did not face this issue. This lead me to circumvent the problem.